# Read camel context and routes from Database in spring boot app

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using apache camel as my integration framework. I need to modify routes in runtime, So I am trying to read camel context and routes from database. I am developing a spring boot app. Is there any way to read routes from database and add to my spring boot app.

Comment: In our product we're using the Apache Camel Spring DSL which means that all the camel  stuff is written in XML. This camel configuration file is read using the spring GenericXmlApplicationContext and after loading the file we retrieve the producer template and actually make a call to a camel endpoint.

At runtime we allow customer to reload the camel configuration file. Which results in the camel context and producers being stopped and then the new file is read

We're not reading it from a database but just from filesystem but that could be changed easily

Comment: At the time customer make changes in camel configuration file. How it is updated in the context?
Also we are using different xml files for each routes and context.